# Python - .append not working in if statement

Tags: python, list, append

I am making a text based game but I am coming into a problem appending a list.

The starting commands you can do are in the list.

```
room1_commands = ['help', 'look']
```

If they use the 'look' command it starts up this.

```
if ask == 'look':
    print ('You see a fireplace.')
    room1_commands.append('fireplace')
```

To my knowledge that should add fireplace to the list of commands but it doesn't.

I have noticed that if I add...

```
print (room1_commands)
```

right after the append it shows it appended, but if I don't indent it so it doesn't sit inside the if statement it only prints out 'help' and 'look'

This is the whole statement (including the help statement which prints out the command list)

```
def room1():
    ask = input()

    room1_commands = ['help', 'look']

    if ask == 'help':
        print ('Usable Commands')
        print (room1_commands)
        room1()

    elif ask == 'look':
        print ('You see a fireplace')
        room1_commands.append('fireplace')
        room1()
```

Comment: It does, your code as posted works just fine. But only if `ask` equals `'look'` exactly. Does the message print at all?

Comment: Works for me: http://codepad.org/BT0Mh9c9 Maybe `ask == 'look\n'` or something?

Comment: What else do you do with `room1_commands`?

Comment: How can you tell that `'fireplace'` isn't added?

Comment: It works fine and there's nothing wrong with your code.. It seems you're printing the array before even appending! Post both of your cases where you are printing the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a recursive function, each time `room1` gets called, `room1_commands` is being set to `['help', 'look']` again. To fix it, you should move `room1_commands = ['help', 'look']` to outside of the function like this:

```
room1_commands = ['help', 'look']

def room1():
    ask = input()

    if ask == 'help':
        print ('Usable Commands')
        print (room1_commands)
        room1()

    elif ask == 'look':
        print ('You see a fireplace')
        room1_commands.append('fireplace')
        room1()
```